# Netsuite: Text Area Online Forms

Tags: html, css, netsuite

I read the article on [adjusting height of text box](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27242/kw/online%20form%20text%20area) on SuiteAnswers. However, it doesn't seem to work for me. When I took a field that was text area (I also tried it with long text), and made the width 75, nothing changed in my online form. When I changed the height to 5, this did change. I looked at the HTML for the text area and it shows cols = "-1" and rows = "5". Rows changed with height (expected), but cols never changed. I tested this with various numbers etc.

Anyone else notice this? Am I doing something wrong? How can I change the width of a text area in an Online Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you linked says that you can set the width on the Display tab of the custom field but like you, I couldn't get this to work.

There's a note that says the value is overridden at *Setup -> Support -> Online Case Forms*.  There is a Width column here and changing this value worked for me for both height and width.

The document says it's for **Online Case Forms** but I found that setting the width in an **Online Customer Form** worked as well (*Setup -> Marketing -> Online Customer Forms*).

Comment: I checked, I don't have an Online Customer Form that is attached to what I am doing. I have just a Marketing Template that is of type Online Form. Do I NEED to create an Online Form? I don't understand why I would just to overwrite a setting that should be "taking".

Comment: If the template is associated with a custom record then you can change the width of a text area field by editing the custom record, then editing the online form associated with that record/template combination.

*Setup -> Customization -> Record Types -> [Custom Record Name] -> Online Forms -> [Form Name]*

I've verified that setting the width here for a text area woks for the associated online form.

Comment: I found there was an Online Customer Form attached. I found it by going to the custom record>Online Forms. I was trying to search for it by going to Forms and find it from there